# SignalR v2 Cannot find method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I'm learning SignalR and I'm getting this error in Google Chrome's debug:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'MoveShape' of undefined
```

My hub class in MVC

```
public class MoveShapeHub : Hub
{
    public void MoveShape(int x, int y)
    {
        Clients.Caller.shapeMoved(Context.ConnectionId, x, y);
    }
}
```

Javascript file

```
$(function () {
var hub = $.connection.MoveShapeHub;
var $shape = $('#shape');

$.extend(hub, {
    shapeMoved: function (cid, x, y) {
        if (cid !== $.connection.hub.id) {
            $shape.css({ left: x, top: y });
        }
    }
});

$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    $shape.draggable({
        drag: function () {
            hub.MoveShape(this.offsetLeft, this.offsetTop || 0);
        }
    });
});
});
```

Script refences in HTML

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Application/MoveShape.js"></script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="shape" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color:#f00"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, can you show us your startup class where you call `MapSignalR()`?

Assuming that you have done that correctly, the first thing that I see that is off is the following:

```
var hub = $.connection.MoveShapeHub;
```

The "/signalr/hubs" script is responsible for defining `$.connection.moveShapeHub`. Notice how `moveShapeHub` is defined using the lower camel case convention common to JavaScript instead of the Pascal case convention common to C#.

This means that the above line should be modified to use the lower camel case convention:

```
var hub = $.connection.moveShapeHub;
```

If you would prefer to use Pascal case, you can do so by using the HubName attribute.

```cs
[HubName("MoveShapeHub")]
public class MoveShapeHub : Hub
```

A name specified by the HubName attribute won't be re-cased by the /signalr/hubs script. http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#getproxy

---

Secondly, you should be putting your client-side hub callbacks on `$.connection.moveShapeHub.client` object instead of directly on `$.connection.moveShapeHub`. This means that `$.extend(hub, { //...` should be `$.extend(hub.client, {` instead.

---

It is also concerning that you use an app root relative path for all your scripts *except* /signalr/hubs. This shouldn't be a problem if your app root is the root of the domain, but I would change the /signalr/hubs reference to also be app root relative to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this instead

```
var hub = $.connection.moveShapeHub;
```